# Remove repeating code

Tags: javascript, loops, refactoring

How would I write this code without all the duplication

```
    // I have a loop which decrements m each time
    // set m to the starting point
    m = mid
    // set f to a calculated array value
    f = dict[l].substr( l * --m, l )
    while (f.substr(0,x) === word && (!limit || matches.length < limit)){
        matches.push(f);
        // same as what was defined outside the while loop
        // which seems to me like unnecessary repetition
        f = dict[l].substr( l * --m, l )
    }
    // then I repeat it all, but incrementing m
    // reset m to the starting point
    m = mid
    f = dict[l].substr( l * m++, l )
    while (f.substr(0,x) === word && (!limit || matches.length < limit)){
        matches.push(f);
        f = dict[l].substr( l * m++, l )
    }
```

There are two parts...

1. each block contains a repeating `f = ...` part
2. the blocks are repeated, only changing the increment/decrement of `m`

---

EDIT: What the code does...

`mid` represents an arbitrary entry point into an alphabetically sorted list of fixed length words with no separators. I am aiming to list all the words that match a set prefix, so must find all the words backwards of the arbitrary `mid` point (as entered by binary search method) and also forwards.

---

Edit: Further details...

dictionary looks like this:

```
dict = [
  "", // offset other values to equal word length
  "ai",    // all length 1
  "inatonuptogo",    // all length 2
  "catcrydogendgodhamhathit",    // all length 3
  "foodhackhallhandhardhatehatshavehellridewood" // all length 4
]
```

`l` is word length of searched words, so `dict[l]` is one row of words from the dictionary, of length `l`.

I am modifying [John Resig's binary search method](http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/) so that it will match a prefix rather than a whole word, and return a set of results, rather than a truthy value. I am also putting a limit in there, as I will be using this for an autocomplete function which only requires a few returned values, not all matches.

Comment: It would help if you gave us an executive summary of what the code actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might pull the loops into a function, since aside from the increment/decrement, they are identical:

```
function helperFunction(m, f, l, mid, dict, matches, limit, increment)
{
    m = mid;

    if (increment)
        f = dict[l].substr(l * m++, l);
    else f = dict[l].substr(l * --m, l);

    while (f.substr(0, x) === word && (!limit || matches.length < limit))
    {
        matches.push(f);
        f = dict[l].substr(l * m, l);

        if (increment)
            f = dict[l].substr(l * m++, l);
        else f = dict[l].substr(l * --m, l);
    }
}
```

I've included all the variables in the argument list since their scope is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a function and pass in a delta. Since m++ is adding +1 to m and m-- is adding -1 to m, you can call for example:

```
 function foo(mid, dict, delta) {
 m = mid
 //   f = dict[l].substr( l * m += delta, l )
    f = dict[l].substr( l * m, l );
    m += delta;
    while (f.substr(0,x) === word && (!limit || matches.length < limit)){
        matches.push(f);
        // f = dict[l].substr( l * m += delta, l )
        f = dict[l].substr( l * m, l );
        m += delta;
    }
    return matches;
}

matches = foo(mid, dict, -1);
matches = foo(mid, dict, +1);
```

I'm only pulling out matches as a return value because I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but it should show you the idea.

Comment: this looks good... is there any way to prevent the `f = ...` line from being duplicated?

Comment: Actually I've spotted an error: (l * m += delta) is obviously wrong, it's an illegal lvalue. It'd have to be (l * m) and update m in the next statement. I'll update the code in my answer.

Comment: Since the f = ... content is repeated, you could rewrite the while loop into a do {..} while(..) loop which would execute the code once before testing the condition.

Comment: I can't see how to make the do while loop, as it should never run unless the condition is met at least once

Comment: @BillyMoon: Make it an infinite loop `do {...} while(true);`, and bring the condition inside the loop at the bottom to either do the `.push()`, or do a `break;` when the condition fails. `if(f.substr...) matches.push(f); else break;`

Comment: ...or instead of the `break;`, you could store the return value of the `.push()` or a falsy value. `var continue_loop = (f.substr...) ? matches.push(f) : 0;` Then have your `do-while` look like this... `do {...} while(continue_loop)`

Comment: could I just do `while(true){ if( f.substr... ){ matches.push(f)... } else { break } }`

Comment: Turns out there is still a glitch in your solution, because in the original code, the decrementing happens before the value is used, and incrementing after

Answer (score 0):

@Billy Moon, can you validate this code below?

```
function foo(flag, m) { return dict[l].substr( l * (Boolean(flag)) ? --m : m++), l ); }
var flag = 1;
do {
    m = mid
    f = foo(flag, m)
    while (f.substr(0,x) === word && (!limit || matches.length < limit)){
        matches.push(f);
        f = foo(flag, m)
    }
    flag--;
} while(flag > -1)
```

I hope may help you.

Comment: Beware recursion - IE barfs when you recurs more than 20 deep, IIRC.